# Download zip is invalid

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a simple aspx page where is in the codebehind I am creating a zip file and streaming it back. Everything worked fine while I kept all my code inside of page_load method. Now I am executing the code on a button click. After download Windows cannot open the zip saying it is invalid. Here is my code:

```
<body style="height: 100%; overflow: hidden" onload="return onBodyLoad();">
<script>
    function onBodyLoad() {
        document.getElementById("ExportBtn").click();
    }
</script>

protected void ExportBtn_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // prepare zip
   .....
   // send zip back
   Response.Clear();
   Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileToDownload);
   Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
   Response.BinaryWrite(File.ReadAllBytes(zipPath));
}
```

The same code wihtout a button click runs fine from the page_load which currently looks like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. All I needed is Response.End(); as the last statement.